# What <T> is described into my value comparison program?

Tags: c#, comparison

I would like to know what `<T>` is used for here into my program.

My was writing my program (I'm a beginner!) `Default value comparison`.

Look at my program:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

    class MyProgram
    {
        //I don't understand this, What "CompareToDefault<T>(T value)" and "where T : IComparable<T>" is describing for, Can you explain pls..?

        static int CompareToDefault<T>(T value)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return value.CompareTo(default(T));
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault("x"));
            Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(10));
            Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(0));
            Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(-10));
            Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(DateTime.MinValue));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generics.  It essentially means that you can call the CompareToDefault method using any type that implements `IComparable<T>`

T is a 'placeholder' for the type you wish to use.

I would suggest reading up on generics here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic method, whose value can be the instance of any `Type` that implements `IComparable<T>`

[**Read More at MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Any class **or** structure that implements  `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I've meant ;) @AmitJoki

Answer (score 0):

Its [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).Putting it very,very simply instead of you having to write several methods to implement this behaviour(in your case compare T and default of T),one for int,one for double,datetime,so on....you get only one method that can do it all.Another simplystic view is to replace T for the data type you are using,for example int,you pass an int value to the method,now replace all T`s with int,it will compare your int value to its default one,if it  was double imagine the same.The where keyword means a constraint on the type of T,in your case it means the type you use must implement Icomparable and thats why in the method you can call compareTo() on T.

Here is some good reading for you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx